# What are typefaces similar to AMS Euler but suitable for text?

Tags: fonts, typefaces

I like the shapes of [AMS euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler). I would like to use it for text, but it is made just of math typesetting, so it is missing some basic glyphs like hyphen, dashes, quotation marks and letters with diacritics, and the letters are too spaced apart.

What are typefaces like AMS Euler but suitable for text? The idea is that the typeface would be upright, cursive-like, ideally with good coverage of characters and looking at least somewhat serious. I tried [Recursive](https://www.recursive.design/) with CASL and CRSV set to 1, but that looks too goofy.

Comment: As mentioned in your linked wiki, did you try Palatino, Adlus, or Concrete Roman? Concrete was made specifically to pair with Euler: https://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf

Comment: @Yorik Concrete Roman is interesting. It looks like a typewriter typeface. What is Adlus? I can't find it. I like Palatino, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Adlus is a typo it should have been Aldus

Answer (score 0):

Andika, Sassoon Sans, FF Nexus Sans italic spring to mind.

Answer (score 0):

The Latin part of [Aref Ruqaa](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Aref+Ruqaa?subset=latin&noto.script=Latn) is EMS Euler but spaced for text.
[image]

Comment: Aref Ruquaa is nice, but its coverage of Latin characters is bad. ([test with some characters with diacritics](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Aref+Ruqaa?subset=latin&noto.script=Latn&preview.text=p%C5%99%C3%ADb%C4%9Bhov%C3%A1%20k%C5%AF%C5%BEi%C4%8Dka&preview.text_type=custom))

Comment: I was looking also for a typeface for typesetting mathematics like Euler but good for whole words in math formulae. This might be good, but I hope that I won't want to use diacritics there.